# FCM token is not generating on web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, frontend

Token is not generating on the web...........................................................................................................................

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
heloooo


</body>
</html>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging=firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
console.log('Have permission');
return messaging.getToken();
})
.then(function(token){
console.log(this.token);
})

.catch(function(err){
console.log('Error occured.');
})
</script>
```

this is my code sorry i can't show my fcm initiation code completely

```
error on my console
hello.html:29 Have permission
hello.html:33 null
hello.html:34 undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply your API key when initialising

Comment: i supplied api key

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my computer right now but I encountered a similar problem too. I had to compose the API key from a token and secret (if I remember correctly). I will try and send through code shortly if you're still stuck

Comment: yes i am still stuck if  u send the code, that will be grateful

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, just a moment - I'll track down the code

Comment: I seem to be having issues now as well - request permission for notifications is failing for some reason, despite my settings permitting notifications

Comment: A few things to try,

Check you have the gcm_sender_id in your manifest.json (and that this is properly registering when you web app loads), see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_the_browser_to_receive_messages

Comment: Also might be worth running this over HTTPS

Comment: Or if possible, deploying your test app to firebase and running from there